# Android: Reading contents from root Application folder.

Tags: java, android, file

I'm currently trying to read contents from a root directory of an android application. I've implemented all the permissions in my manifest as stated below:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and for my code:

```
public void copytoFileDestination(){

    //get the root path of the application. 
    String rootPath = getFilesDir().getPath() + "/images/"; 
    File destination = new File(rootPath);

    String imgPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/somefilename.jpg"
    File source = new File(imgPath);

    try{ 
        //copy source location to destination directory
        copyFile(source, destination);

        //display all the contents of rootPath! How? Attempt:  
        File[] files = destination.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    private void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
    destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
    if (destination != null && source != null) {
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        Log.d("copy file", "complete");
    }
    if (source != null) {
        source.close();
    }
    if (destination != null) {
        destination.close();
    }

}
```

I just wanna copy from the source (image path) to destination (root path) then display the contents of the destination. However, I got a null exception at files.length, meaning that the destination file contains...no file? Is it because I could not read from the destination directory?

Can someone enlighten me?

By the way:

- destination.exist() is true.
- destination.canRead() is true.

Do help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I works for me,

```
public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
    destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
    byte[] var1 = new byte[1024];

    int var2;
    while((var2 = source.read(var1)) > 0) {
        destination.write(var1, 0, var2);
    }

    source.close();
    destination.close();
}
```